# Custom post type according to year and month

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called news, but whenever i type the URL mywebsite/2016/12/?post_type=news , it shows all the news without any filtering, is there any code that i have to add anywhere for WordPress show my custom post type according to the year/month ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read using permalinks from the Codex to see if pretty permalinks will solve your problem. https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks